# How do I replace all the apostrophes that come right before or right after a comma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string **aString = "old_tag1,old_tag2,'new_tag1','new_tag2'"** 
I want to replace the apostrophees that come right before or right after a comma. For example in my case the apostrophees enclosing new_tag1 and new_tag2 should be removed.
This is what I have right now

```
aString = aString.gsub("'", "")
```

This is however problematic as it removes any apostrophe inside for example if I had 'my_tag's' instead of 'new_tag1'. How do I get rid of only the apostrophes that come before or after the commas  ?

My desired output is

```
aString = "old_tag1,old_tag2,new_tag1,new_tag2"
```

Comment: Please show the desired result for your example.

Comment: Aside: the Ruby convention is to use [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for the names of local variables and methods. Here, for example, you might use `astring`, `a_string` or `str`. It's just a convention, so you don't have to do that, but 99%+ of Rubiest adhere to the convention.

Comment: Your desired output does not match with your description of the algorithm. Where did the apostrophe after `new_tag2` go? It's not right before or right after a comma, so why was it removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the question, "I want to replace the apostrophes that come right before or right after a comma".

```
r = /
    (?<=,) # match a comma in a positive lookbehind
    \'     # match an apostrophe
    |      # or
    \'     # match an apostrophe
    (?=,)  # match a comma in a positive lookahead
    /x     # free-spacing regex definition mode        

aString = "old_tag1,x'old_tag2'x,x'old_tag3','new_tag1','new_tag2'"

aString.gsub(r, '')
  #=> => "old_tag1,x'old_tag2'x,x'old_tag3,new_tag1,new_tag2'"
```

If the objective is instead to remove single quotes enclosing a substring when the left quote is at the the beginning of the string or is immediately preceded by a comma and the right quote is at the end of the string or is immediately followed by comma, several approaches are possible. One is to use a single, modified regex, as @Dimitry has done. Another is to split the string on commas, process each string in the resulting array and them join the modified substrings,  separated by commas.

```
r = /
    \A     # match beginning of string
    \'     # match single quote
    .*     # match zero or more characters
    \'     # match single quote
    \z     # match end of string
    /x     # free-spacing regex definition mode

aString.split(',').map { |s| (s =~ r) ? s[1..-2] : s }.join(',')
  #=> "old_tag1,x'old_tag2'x,x'old_tag3',new_tag1,new_tag2"
```

Note:

```
arr = aString.split(',')
  #=> ["old_tag1", "x'old_tag2'x", "x'old_tag3'", "'new_tag1'", "'new_tag2'"]
"old_tag1"     =~ r #=> nil
"x'old_tag2'x" =~ r #=> nil
"x'old_tag3'"  =~ r #=> nil
"'new_tag1'"   =~ r #=> 0
"'new_tag2'"   =~ r #=> 0
```

Comment: Pay attention, the last apostrophe is still there

Comment: @Dimitry, the asker said "I want to replace the apostrophes that come right before or right after a comma." That's unambiguous and is what I've done. The asker does say that the apostrophes enclosing "new_tag2" should be removed but that is inconsistent with the stated objective.

Comment: I believe you made it correct according to the question, but I feel like it doesn't make too much sense without that last part. Let's wait the answer for your clarification request.

Comment: Could you edit your question somewhere? I can't revoke it now.

Comment: For `str = "'new_tag's'"`, `str.gsub(r, '') #=>"'new_tag's'"`. I believe OP would want `"new_tag's"` returned.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, but-but,-but there is no comma in that string. :-) In any case, we are on thin ice if try to figure out what the asker is thinking when the question is clear, but then the asker add something that is contradictory. Best to explain the problem in a comment and request clarification.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry I wished to take out the last apostrophee as well. My bad

Comment: codigomonstruo,  you'll see that I added to my answer to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is to use regex as well, but in a slightly other way:

```
aString = "old_tag1,old_tag2,'new_tag1','new_tag2','new_tag3','new_tag4's'"
aString.gsub /(?<=^|,)'(.*?)'(?=,|$)/, '\1\2\3'
#=> "old_tag1,old_tag2,new_tag1,new_tag2,new_tag3,new_tag4's"
```

The idea is to find a substring with bounding apostrophes and paste it back without it.

```rb
regex = /
  (?<=^|,) # watch for start of the line or comma before
  '        # find an apostrophe
  (.*?)    # get everything between apostrophes in a non-greedy way
  '        # find a closing apostrophe
  (?=,|$)  # watch after for the comma or the end of the string
/x
```

The replacement part just paste back the content of the first, second, and third groups (everything between parenthesis).

Thanks for [@Cary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) for `/x` modificator for regexes, I didn't know about it! Extremely useful for explanation.

Comment: I didn't %) It was in the tag body

Answer (score 0):

## Non regex replacement

Regular expressions can get really ugly.  There is a simple way to do it with just string replacement:  search for the pattern `,'` and `',` and replace with `,`

```
aString.gsub(",'", ",").gsub("',", ",")
=> "old_tag1,old_tag2,new_tag1,new_tag2'"
```

This leaves the trailing `'`, but that is easy to remove with `.chomp("'")`.  A leading `'` can be removed with a simple regex `.gsub(/^'/, "")`